# how I can solve aperture function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want solve a function called aperture which accept a number and an array that should return new array that should be composed of subarrays the size of the number with consecutive elements, for example aperture:

```
(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the issues?

Comment: it doesn't work with any of the other examples, its my fault not to post all the examples:
aperture(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
aperture(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
aperture(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
aperture(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
aperture(5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty array whose length is equal to the given number and use `reduce()` on it.

```js
const aperture = (num,arr) => [...Array(num)].reduce((ac,_,i) => {
  ac.push(arr.slice(i,num+i));
  return ac;
},[])

console.log(aperture(3,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```